# Why is my Pipelinewise ETL not inserting rows into Snowflake?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, singer-io

I'm using the Pipelinewise ETL utility which implements the Singer.io spec. Data is making it from my postgres instance -> s3 -> Snowflake stage but the data is not being inserted into Snowflake tables. Anyone have any ideas?

I've tried:

- `sync_tables`
- Deleting `~/.pipelinewise` and removing the docker volumes for the pipelinewise container
- Dropping all the Snowflake tables

The tables get recreated, but they're empty...

```
time=2021-04-07 23:56:09 logger_name=pipelinewise.fastsync.commons.target_snowflake log_level=INFO message=Uploading to S3 bucket: sightly-staging-pipelinewise, local file: /root/.pipelinewise/tmp/pipelinewise_postgres-staging-tap_brand.trend_brand_profile_question_mapping_20210407-235606-434637_fastsync_7NZCNBPA.csv.gz, S3 key: snowflake-imports/pipelinewise_po
stgres-staging-tap_brand.trend_brand_profile_question_mapping_20210407-235606-434637_fastsync_7NZCNBPA.csv.gz
time=2021-04-07 23:56:16 logger_name=pipelinewise.fastsync.commons.target_snowflake log_level=INFO message=Loading snowflake-imports/pipelinewise_postgres-staging-tap_brand.trend_brand_profile_question_mapping_20210407-235606-434637_fastsync_7NZCNBPA.csv.gz into Snowflake...
time=2021-04-07 23:56:19 logger_name=pipelinewise.fastsync.commons.target_snowflake log_level=INFO message=Loading into BRAND."TREND_BRAND_PROFILE_QUESTION_MAPPING_TEMP": {"inserts": 0, "updates": 0, "size_bytes": 147}
time=2021-04-07 23:56:19 logger_name=pipelinewise.fastsync.commons.target_snowflake log_level=INFO message=Deleting snowflake-imports/pipelinewise_postgres-staging-tap_brand.trend_brand_profile_question_mapping_20210407-235606-434637_fastsync_7NZCNBPA.csv.gz from S3...
```

Note the output:

```
{"inserts": 0, "updates": 0, "size_bytes": 147}
```

Comment: Just as an experiment - can you try renaming the files? Any more details would be helpful too

Comment: @FelipeHoffa which files? In S3? They're deleted and re-created on every import step

Comment: With the same name? What if the files are created with a new name?